# Is it possible to rewrite this SQL query with multiple Inner Joins so that it executes much faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with 200,000 rows. I have created a View where I am removing slices of data from this table based on different criteria which fit my definition of what constitutes a duplicate record. I have the code for doing so below and I was wondering if anyone could suggest a faster/more efficient method of writing this query. It currently takes about 20 seconds to execute but I was hoping for a couple of seconds at most to execute this query if not less. I am using SQL Server 2005. My knowledge of SQL is very beginner and I appreciate any help.

```
WITH dsm_hardware_basic_cte AS
(
 SELECT    TOP 100 PERCENT
           dbo.dsm_hardware_basic.[UUID]
          ,dbo.dsm_hardware_basic.[Name]
          ,dbo.dsm_hardware_basic.[LastAgentExecution]
          ,dbo.dsm_hardware_basic.[MaxUserRegistration]
          ,REPLACE(RIGHT([MaxUserRegistration], CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE([MaxUserRegistration])) - 1),'_ADMIN','') AS [MaxUserUsername]
          ,dbo.dsm_hardware_basic.[LastUserRegistration]
          ,REPLACE(RIGHT([LastUserRegistration], CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE([LastUserRegistration])) - 1),'_ADMIN','') AS [LastUserUsername]
          ,dbo.dsm_hardware_basic.[IPAddress]
          ,dbo.dsm_hardware_basic.[HostName]
          ,dbo.dsm_hardware_basic.[MACAddress]
 FROM      dbo.dsm_hardware_basic
)

SELECT     TOP 100 PERCENT
           dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[UUID]
          ,dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[Name]
          ,dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[LastAgentExecution]
          ,dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[MaxUserRegistration]
          ,dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[LastUserRegistration]
          ,dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[IPAddress]
          ,dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[HostName]
          ,dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[MACAddress]
FROM       dsm_hardware_basic_cte
           INNER JOIN
           (
            SELECT    [UUID]
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [MACAddress] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [NameMACRowNum]
            FROM      dsm_hardware_basic_cte
           ) AS duplicate_NameMAC_filtered
             ON duplicate_NameMAC_filtered.[UUID] = dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[UUID]
            AND duplicate_NameMAC_filtered.[NameMACRowNum] = 1
           INNER JOIN
           (
            SELECT    [UUID]
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [HostName] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [NameHostNameRowNum]
            FROM      dsm_hardware_basic_cte
           ) AS duplicate_NameHostName_filtered
             ON duplicate_NameHostName_filtered.[UUID] = dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[UUID]
            AND duplicate_NameHostName_filtered.[NameHostNameRowNum] = 1
           INNER JOIN
           (
            SELECT    [UUID]
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [HostName], [MACAddress] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [HostNameMACRowNum]
            FROM      dsm_hardware_basic_cte
           ) AS duplicate_HostNameMAC_filtered
             ON duplicate_HostNameMAC_filtered.[UUID] = dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[UUID]
            AND duplicate_HostNameMAC_filtered.[HostNameMACRowNum] = 1
           INNER JOIN
           (
            SELECT    [UUID]
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [HostName], [IPAddress] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [HostNameIPAddressRowNum]
            FROM      dsm_hardware_basic_cte
           ) AS duplicate_HostNameIPAddress_filtered
             ON duplicate_HostNameIPAddress_filtered.[UUID] = dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[UUID]
            AND duplicate_HostNameIPAddress_filtered.[HostNameIPAddressRowNum] = 1
           INNER JOIN
           (
            SELECT    [UUID]
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [MaxUserUsername] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [NameMaxUserRowNum]
            FROM      dsm_hardware_basic_cte
           ) AS duplicate_NameMaxUser_filtered
             ON duplicate_NameMaxUser_filtered.[UUID] = dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[UUID]
            AND duplicate_NameMaxUser_filtered.[NameMaxUserRowNum] = 1
           INNER JOIN
           (
            SELECT    [UUID]
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [LastUserUsername] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [NameLastUserRowNum]
            FROM      dsm_hardware_basic_cte
           ) AS duplicate_NameLastUser_filtered
             ON duplicate_NameLastUser_filtered.[UUID] = dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[UUID]
            AND duplicate_NameLastUser_filtered.[NameLastUserRowNum] = 1
```

Comment: Since you're using SQL Server, first step is to look at the actual Query Plan in SSMS. Does it "suggest" any indices? Where does the Query Plan show where most of the time is taken?

Comment: how often is this query executed ?

Comment: I don't understand Query Plans very well yet. Still teaching myself things as I go along. I did capture an execution plan for a query earlier today and I think it took about 13 or 14 seconds. You can find it here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/lvfs7tg2iwnp2a7/execution_plan.sqlplan

Comment: This query is the base for every other query I have. It is always the first in any list of joins and it is executed quite often.

Comment: From code you have provided, all the columns you need are coming from 'dsm_hardare_basic_cte', is that correct? Are all other inner joins you have underneath, basically to filter your records ?

Comment: Are you sure the CTE is materialized? As far as I know, the "TOP 100 Percent" is almost always ignored. You should try TOP 12E PERCENT" instead, or TOP + some very large number like TOP 434314111.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your needs are, but I'd try re-writing the query as such:

```
WITH dsm_hardware_basic_cte AS (
 SELECT
    d.[UUID]
    ,d.[Name]
    ,d.[LastAgentExecution]
    ,d.[MaxUserRegistration]
    ,REPLACE(RIGHT([MaxUserRegistration], CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE([MaxUserRegistration])) - 1),'_ADMIN','') AS [MaxUserUsername]
    ,d.[LastUserRegistration]
    ,REPLACE(RIGHT([LastUserRegistration], CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE([LastUserRegistration])) - 1),'_ADMIN','') AS [LastUserUsername]
    ,d.[IPAddress]
    ,d.[HostName]
    ,d.[MACAddress]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [MACAddress] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [NameMACRowNum]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [HostName] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [NameHostNameRowNum]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [HostName], [MACAddress] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [HostNameMACRowNum]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [HostName], [IPAddress] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [HostNameIPAddressRowNum]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [MaxUserUsername] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [NameMaxUserRowNum]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [LastUserUsername] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [NameLastUserRowNum]
 FROM      dbo.dsm_hardware_basic as d
)

SELECT
    c.[UUID]
    ,c.[Name]
    ,c.[LastAgentExecution]
    ,c.[MaxUserRegistration]
    ,c.[LastUserRegistration]
    ,c.[IPAddress]
    ,c.[HostName]
    ,c.[MACAddress]
FROM       dsm_hardware_basic_cte as c
WHERE
    c.[NameMACRowNum] = 1
    or c.[NameHostNameRowNum] = 1
    or c.[HostNameMACRowNum] = 1
    or [HostNameIPAddressRowNum] = 1
    or [NameMaxUserRowNum] = 1
    or [NameLastUserRowNum] = 1
```

I think that your query and mine are logically equivalent. The optimizer might be smart enough to have reduced your query to mine, but give it a spin and see! A couple of notes:

1. I used table aliases in order to make it a bit more readable (in my opinion)
2. I removed the "top 100 percent" clause from your select. It's not needed; that's typically a hack that people put in place so they can do an order by in the view to get, well, an "ordered view". Don't do that. :)

Comment: With a few modifications to the code that had more to do with how my full query works, I was able to get this to work and it was a bit faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

according to your Query Plan the sorting by LastAgentExecution takes 19% of time. Start by creating an index on this column.

However, if I were you I would changed the habit of using "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [MACAddress] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC)" type of syntax, because it does not seem to be very effective

Comment: How do you create an index on a column? Also I have seen people mention indexing a column in other question/answers as well and I was wondering if you could give a brief explanation of why indexing a column makes queries run faster?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what else I could use other than the ROW_NUMBER function in a View. I wrote a solution using temporary tables which was blazing fast but later learned that I could not use temporary tables in a View.

Comment: Actually, found an excellent explanation of indexes here: http://odetocode.com/articles/237.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inner joins, try replacing them with the "Exists" clause like this

```
WHERE      EXISTS           
           ((SELECT [UUID],[NameMACRowNum]
                FROM
                        (SELECT    [UUID]
                                 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [MACAddress] ORDER BY [LastAgentExecution] DESC) AS [NameMACRowNum]
                        FROM      dsm_hardware_basic_cte) AS duplicate_NameMAC_filtered
            WHERE duplicate_NameMAC_filtered.[UUID] = dsm_hardware_basic_cte.[UUID]
            AND duplicate_NameMAC_filtered.[NameMACRowNum] = 1)
```

Not sure it should be Exists or Not Exists, but it will be simple to change once the rest is working.